# Using Form 1 while Form 2 is open - C#

Tags: c#, forms

I have used Google to find a solution on this without any luck, hoping you guys/girls can help me out.

Code :

```
private void funButtonToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var FF = new FunForm();
            FF.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Very simple, opens up a second Form.
However, when this form launches it disables access to my main form.
Am I able to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `FF.Show()` rather than `FF.ShowDialog()`

Answer (score 2):

Is FF.Show() what you want? It displays the second form non-modal. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show(v=vs.110).aspx) for details.